# laravel 5.2 not working on server giving 403 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project picked up from GitHub , that's working fine on localhost , but it's not working on server giving 403 error, index.php file is in public directory.

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';    
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

if I put index.php in root , it's worked by css and js file not working.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file in the root folder. Please post the content of the same.

Comment: @BharatGeleda no .htaccess file in root, its in public directory, why its working on localhost perfectly

Comment: Does the server's error log tell you something about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase no error logs are being made, its 403  error

Comment: Does your webserver point to the public directory? It should be set to that and not on the root

Comment: @SvenHakvoort how can I check this ?

Comment: What do you use as a webserver? How is that configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your webserver, the main directory has to point to public directory.
On Froxlor is DocumentRoot: path/to/public/
On cPanel is Root dir (in my case)

You can put your index file in root dir too, but it's not recommended, because you have to chenge the paths. That's why your css and js files not working.

Comment: thanks , how can I point "the main directory to public directory", means .env file or any other file

Comment: In your webserver. When you creade a domain or subdomain or addon domain, you have to give a path to directory on the server (that directory is main directory for the domain).